# Why do I have more particles in the render than the viewport?

Tags: particles

So I've got two emitters, each has two particle systems, all throwing hearts. When I render the animation, I get maybe 3x as many hearts as I want, which makes it hard to balance it all.

Here's the viewport, with all particles baked, playhead at frame 139

[image]

Here's the render, which I stopped at frame 139 because it's choked with hearts

[image]

I've seen viewport vs render amounts in the hair section, but I can't find anything that relates to emitters.

Comment: sounds like your children settings differ between render and viewport

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Properties editor > Particles > Viewport Displaly > Amount

[image]

Properties editor > Particles > Children > Display Amount

[image]

Comment: oh god wont someone think of the children.
yes. i only had kids on the first of the particle systems, which made this just that little bit harder to find.
Thankyou Vklidu and Frederik